# Regex replace string which is not float

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, where I need to parse it as a float, but first I need to replace it, if it is not a number (an integer or a float), so I am trying to create an regular expression to do it

My tries results in *NaN*

One of my best tries is

```
var $replace = $text.replace(/^[^d.]*/, '');
var $float = parseFloat($replace);
```

Can anybody tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: your regex says to replace zero or more characters that are not a `d` or a `.` from the beginning of your string with nothing... What are you *trying* to replace/remove exactly?

Comment: I am trying to replace everything, that are not a digit (or a . (used in a float))

Comment: Why are you prepending a dollar sign to your variables?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what `$text` might look like, and what you want `$replace` and `$float` to look like in those cases?

Comment: @NullUserException It depends on, which server-side programming language, I am using, and right here I am using PHP, which uses dollar signs in variables

Comment: @ruakh $text Can be "<input name="field1", where $replace and $float should be null or something similar. And $text can also be 443 e.g.

Comment: @The87Boy No it doesn't. JavaScript is completely independent from PHP, it wouldn't make any difference whatsoever if you named those variables `replace`, `text`, etc. (except they wouldn't look as ugly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (! isNaN($text))
  $float = parseFloat($text);
else
  $float = 0; // or whatever
```

Comment: This only answers part of the question, because it doesn't address the faulty regex the OP is currently using.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to replace everything thats not a digit, then try this:

```
var $replace = $text.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
var $float = parseFloat($replace);
```

This will replace a string of `"123a3d2"` with a string of `"12332"`.

Comment: What if `$text = 'hello.world'`?

Comment: @NullUserException Then `$float == NaN`. I mean, personally, I would do a *validation* that this is in fact a number, rather than stripping out characters. But that's not the question the op asked.

Comment: `/[^\d.]/g` allow to put as many `.` as you want. For example `12.34.5` and `1....2...3..45` works.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to strip "non-numeric" characters from the beginning of the string before converting it to float. A naive approach would be:

```
var s = input.replace(/^[^\d.]+/, '');
var n = parseFloat(s);
```

This works for inputs like "foo123" but will fail on "foo.bar.123". To parse this we need a more sophisticated regexp:

```
var s = input.replace(/^(.(?!\d)|\D)+/, '');
var n = parseFloat(s);
```

Another method is to strip the input char by char until we find a valid float:

```
function findValidFloat(str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var f = parseFloat(str.substr(i))
        if (!isNaN(f))
            return f;
    }
    return NaN;
}
```